# How to achieve delete and undo operations on Dismissible widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Questions:

1-) I have a data lists coming from sqlite database and I want to show them in UI. Also when user dismiss a card I want to delete it from database but if user taps undo then I want to bring it back. The problem is when I dismiss a card it's giving error:

***A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree.***

I searched solution for this problem but none of them fit my case because I use Bloc for these operations and other solutions were about setState

You can see in here:
[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXw3A.gif)

2-) Also when I swipe card card's background color clipping:
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/docLN.jpg)

How to fix these issues?

```
return Dismissible(
  key: Key(widget.task.id.toString()),
  background: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
  onDismissed: (direction) async {
    Task copied = widget.task;
    taskBloc.deleteTask(widget.task.id);
    changeValue(widget.task.categoryId, false);
    Flushbar(
      messageText: Text('Task deleted', style: bodyText.copyWith(
        color: Colors.white
      )),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      borderRadius: 8,
      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.infoCircle, color: widget.color),
      flushbarStyle: FlushbarStyle.FLOATING,
      dismissDirection: FlushbarDismissDirection.HORIZONTAL,
      mainButton: FlatButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          taskBloc.addTask(copied);
          changeValue(widget.task.categoryId, true);
        },
        child: Text('Undo', style: bodyText.copyWith(color: widget.color)),
      ),
    )..show(context);
  }),
```

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this passing confirmDismiss in the Dismissible widget as given below which should return either true else false;

```
 confirmDismiss: (val) async {    
 return await  AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Delete'),
      content: Text('Are you sure to delete?'),
      actions:[
        FlatButton(
          child:Text("Yes"),
          onPressed:()=>Navigator.pop(context,true)
        ),
         FlatButton(
          child:Text("No"),
          onPressed:()=>Navigator.pop(context,false)
        ),
      ],
    )??false;    
 }
```

After that the onDismissed is called only when the Yes button is clicked . after the dismissed is called remove the item from the current list

Comment: thanks for reply @Khadga  but I don't want to show dialog, I just want to show Flushbar (kind of snackbar) and if user taps undo button I must bring it back else it must deleted

Comment: Also since I use StreamBuilder to delete, I think it's not necessary to remove item from list because already StreamBuilder refresh itself when anything change (such as deleting an item or adding an item)

Comment: @WildHunter How do you achieved this. Can you share with us? I am also facing same issue. I use SnackBar and reinsert when user click undo press.

Comment: May be we can instead push a snackbar with an undo button. You can implement a timer of 5 seconds to the delete function and also put the snackbar to display for 5 seconds. Once 5 seconds have passed, the snackbar goes away and the item is deleted. 
However, if the user presses undo, it since the item swiped is just temporarily removed, you can use setState(() {}) to bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

```
void _onDismissed(BuildContext context, index) => setState(
    () {
      FavouriteSong favouriteSong = favouriteSongs[index];
      favouriteSongs.removeAt(index);
      BlocProvider.of<FavouriteSongBloc>(context)
          .add(DeleteFavouriteSong(favouriteSong: favouriteSong));

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content:
              AutoSizeText("${favouriteSong.title} ကိုဖျက်လိုက်ပါပြီ။"),
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
          action: SnackBarAction(
            label: 'မဖျက်တော့ပါ',
            onPressed: () {
              favouriteSongs.insert(index, favouriteSong);

              BlocProvider.of<FavouriteSongBloc>(context).add(
                CreateFavouriteSong(favouriteSong: favouriteSong),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forget to remove element to current list and refresh with setState(() {})

```dart
return Dismissible(
  key: Key(widget.task.id.toString()),
  background: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
  onDismissed: (direction) async {
    Task copied = widget.task;
    taskBloc.deleteTask(widget.task.id);
    changeValue(widget.task.categoryId, false);
    setState(() {})
    Flushbar(
      messageText: Text('Task deleted', style: bodyText.copyWith(
        color: Colors.white
      )),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      borderRadius: 8,
      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.infoCircle, color: widget.color),
      flushbarStyle: FlushbarStyle.FLOATING,
      dismissDirection: FlushbarDismissDirection.HORIZONTAL,
      mainButton: FlatButton(
        onPressed: () async {
           // to success rollback you must change id because of (Key(widget.task.id.toString())),
           // otherwise you will get the same error
          taskBloc.addTask(copied);
          changeValue(widget.task.categoryId, true);
        },
        child: Text('Undo', style: bodyText.copyWith(color: widget.color)),
      ),
    )..show(context);
  }),
```